# Using POST and GET directly in PDO bindParam

Tags: php, pdo

In their explanations of PDO, I often see informed writers offer example like these two. The first one uses a simple POST in the bindParam and the second assigns it to a variable first. Before I go about swapping out this old Adobe code for PDO, I'd like to know if one is preferable over the other, i.e. more secure or something else.

```
 $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT whatever FROM whatever WHERE AuthorEmail=:id"); 
 $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['AuthorEmail'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 


 $AuthorEmail = $_POST['AuthorEmail'];

 $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT whatever FROM whatever WHERE AuthorEmail=:id"); 
 $stmt->bindParam(':id', $AuthorEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: there's no difference in "security". it just changes where the value comes from. e.g. if some other code later mangles $_POST, then the `$AuthorEmail` version will retain its value regardless of what $_POST gets changed to.

Comment: In your examples it is fairly academic. Using the `$_POST` variable directly saves you having to create an otherwise redundant variable and use space on the stack for no good reason. However with either method some sanity checking would be advised so you dont store rubbish in your database.

Comment: @Marc B - Thank you. I assumed as much, but my assumptions have proven wrong before. I mean,  it's php, right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Thank you. I was just reading where, these days, using PDO prepared statements, with named parameters and emulate_prepares(false) with a utf8mb4 connection string will absolutely eliminate the danger of sql injection. Thus the remaining danger, XSS is conrolled by escaping everything on the output with htmlspecialchars(,ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'). The upshot was to not actually worry about an angle bracket or a quote showing up in the db so long as it is escaped on the output. Care to comment?

Comment: Only to say that it is **always better** to clean your data before you store it anywhere. Remember it may not be a PHP script that i used to view/manipulate the data once it is stored in a database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - right. That makes sense. Thanks gentlemen.